# For which values of c does the system have a solution?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I was doing my homework and stumbled upon this question where I have a system of 3 equations with 5 unknowns/variables. I got stuck trying to make it into an echelon form of this matrix.

The problem is stated as follows:

> Find which values of *c* does the system have a solution? For each *c*, find all solutions as linear combinations of certain vectors.

In the image below I tried to solve it but got stuck and I'm not sure how to continue this equation..

[image]

Comment: You can continue making $R_2/(-3/2)$, $R_3/(-1/2)$, then $R_3-R_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could u explain how c will become a 0 at the end?

Comment: c won't become 0 in this case. Continuing your work you will get: $x_1+..x_2+..x_3+..x_4=..$, $x_2+..x_3+..x_4=..$, $x_3+..x_4=..$. You can get expression for $x_3$ from last equation, then expression for $x_2$ from second equation, then expression for $x_1$ from first equation. All these expressions will be $x_i(c,x_4)=a_ix_4+b_i(c)$, for example $x_1=5x_4-2c^2+5c+11$. General solution can be expressed in vector form as $X=At+B$, where $B$ is vector of $b_i(c)$, $b_4(c)=0$, $A$ is vector of $a_i$, $a_4=1$, $t$ — arbitrary real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x_5 = c $ and $x_6 = c^2 $, then the system becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} 2&&1&&5&&4&&0&&-1 \\ 1 && -1&& 1 &&-1&&-4&&0 \\ 1 && 0 && 2 && 1 && -1 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $

Solving using Gauss-Jordan elimination, the solutions are

$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -8\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t_1 \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t_2 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ - 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t_3 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

From which it follows that

$x_5 = c = 2 - t_3 $ and $ x_6 = c^2 = t_3 $

Hence, we must have $2 - c = c^2 $, i.e. $c^2 + c - 2 = 0$ which can be factored as $ (c + 2)(c - 1) = 0 $.  Therefore, the two values of $c$ for which there is a solution are $c = -2 $ and $c = 1$.

For $c = -2$, we get $t_3 = 4 $  and for $c = 1$ we get $t_3 = 1 $

Therefore, there are two corresponding sets of solutions:

Case I: for $c = -2$ we get,

$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t_1 \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t_2 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ - 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  $

Case II:  for $c = 1$, we get,

$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -5 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t_1 \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + t_2 \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ - 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  $

Comment: Ahh, like that. I didn't think of making the c also a variable like the others. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you like the solution please accept it and upvote it.  Thanks.

Comment: I accepted the solution but unfortunately cannot upvote yet due to my new account.